# How to add Data From a combobox to a gridview control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, combobox, bind

I want To add The selected product from the Combo box to the grid view.

I have tried it by adding it in list box and it did work but to be more flexible with it I want to try grid view

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    lbl.Text = Billing.SelectedItem.Text; 
    Get.Items.Add(Billing.SelectedItem.Text); 
    Billing.Focus(); 
}
```

I have used this code to add it in the listbox.. And now for more flexibility I want it to do with gridview.

Comment: it's useful to show what you tried when ask a question,please add the code you used too.

Comment: 'code' 
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         lbl.Text = Billing.SelectedItem.Text;
            Get.Items.Add(Billing.SelectedItem.Text);
            Billing.Focus();
                     
        }
'code'
@NiMa

I have used this code to add it in the listbox..
And now for more flexibility i want it to do with gridview.

Comment: can you edit the question with the code and also add the aspx coded ? (so that we other users will not have to search for the code in the comment section?)

Comment: @user3240361 i am really sorry for the trouble next time ill keep that in mind